# Generate multivariate normal matrix issue with accuracy

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to use Cholesky decomposition to generate a multivariate matrix with this: `Y = U + X*L`

```
U is the mean vector: n x m  
L from cholesky: m x m
X is a matrix with univariate normal vectors: n x m
```

After calculating the mean of the simulated matrix, I realized it was off. The reason is that the mean vector is very close to zero, so when adding it to `L*X, L*X dominated the U`. Anyone know how to work around this issue?